# How to have the arctan2 / atan2 function in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode

Is there an arctan2 / atan2 function in LaTeX, which can print an aesthetic result like the other trigonometric functions `\sin` `\cos`... ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `arctan2` is still `arctan`, in my point of view, however, with a specific purpose defined by programming languages rather

Comment: @user31729 It's not just a programming convenience.  They are different mathematical functions with different mathematical meanings and different input/output graphs.  For example arctan( 1 / -1 )=-pi/4, whereas atan2(1,-1)=pi*3/4.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`amsmath` provides `\DeclareMathOperator{\foo}{foo}` to define new operator names that are typeset similar to `\sin` and `\cos`, `\ln`, i.e. upright font and correct spacings.

This can be used with `\atantwo` as well (the `2` isn't allowed as part of the macro name, however, therefor `\atantwo`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\atantwo}{atan2}

\DeclareMathOperator{\arctantwo}{arctan2}


\begin{document}

\[
\atantwo ( y, x)
\]

\[
\arctantwo ( y, x)
\]



\[
\sin (x y)
\]



\end{document}
```

[image]

Note:  The `atan2(y,x)` function determines the angle in polar coordinates and is related to but different than the function `atan(y/x)`.  The two are not interchangeable.  The `atan` function has output range `(-pi/2,pi/2)`, whereas `atan2` has an output range of `(-pi,pi]`.  If `x>0`, then `atan2(y,x)=atan(y/x)`.  If `x<0`, then `atan2(y,x)=atan(y/x) +/- pi`.  And if `x=0` then `atan(y/x)` is undefined while `atan2(y,x)=pi/2` for `y>0` or `-pi/2` for `y<0`.  This definition of `atan2` (or equivalently `arctan2`) is the same both for mathematics and for common programming languages including C, FORTRAN, and matlab.

Comment: Just a quibble: isn't it traditionally defined as `(y,x)` not `(x,y)`?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Depends on the meaning of `x` and `y`, perhaps? ;-) At least for C it's the way you said. I'll change

Comment: If I may date myself, FORTRAN77 defines `atan2(a1,a2)` as `atan(a1/a2)`.  Since `x` and `y` carry customary meanings in a Cartesian system, that is the basis for my quibble.

Comment: Of course atan2(y,x) is ***not*** arctan(y/x); it would be silly to define it this way, wouldn't it?

Comment: @egreg: According to the C language man page, `atan2(y,x)` is the principal value of arctan `y/x`

Comment: Thanks ! The usual convention is to have `y` before `x` when using `atan2`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer According to mathematics, it isn't. ;-)

Comment: @egreg Yes, yes, of course, I am speaking imprecisely.  We know what I meant.  I am an engineer, not a mathematician.

Comment: @egreg: Ah, now I got you: Polar coordinates -- determing the argument phi, this seems to be a special symbol then

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The description at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2 seems quite accurate. Talking about TeX, I wouldn't be displeased by `\DeclareMathOperator{\atantwo}{atan_2}`

Comment: @egreg depends on what kind of mathematics. I'd always assumed that, like `sqrt`, `atan`was properly considered a multiple-branch function. (Of course, `atan2(y,x)` is only the _principal value_ when x is positive, though I thought that was implied)

Comment: @Random832: Since it's not clear what is really meant, it's not worth to argue about the meaning of `atan2` as being used in math or as a programming language function

Comment: What about `atan()`? Is that a built in function?

Comment: *" According to the C language man page, `atan2(y,x)` is the principal value of arctan `y/x`"* The same page goes on to say that the returned value is in the range `[-pi, pi]` which tells you that the author of the page was confused about the meaning of "principle value" in this context. I've used `atan2` in quite a few language and it has always been the quadrant disambiguated version that returns values in a full circle.

Comment: All the C, C++, and Fortran help pages I can find all say that atan2's result is in the range of [-pi,pi], which is the same thing that as the "mathematical" definition.

Answer (score 5):

If you want you can let them be a little bit more intelligent to enable `\atan2` and `\arctan2`

```
\long\def\gobbleone#1{}
\protected\def\atan{\futurelet\tmptoken\doatan}
\protected\def\doatan{\operatorname{atan\ifx\tmptoken22\fi}%
  \ifx\tmptoken2\expandafter\gobbleone\fi}
\protected\def\arctan{\futurelet\tmptoken\doarctan}
\protected\def\doarctan{\operatorname{arc\,tan\ifx\tmptoken22\fi}%
  \ifx\tmptoken2\expandafter\gobbleone\fi}

$\atan2(y, x) \arctan2(y, x) \sin(x, y)$
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `\mathrm`. So:

```
$\mathrm{atan2}$
$\mathrm{arctan2}$
```

Which gives

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is not an operator and the spacing will most likely be incorrect.